# What's the Equivalent of str_replace(array_keys([]), array_values([]), $subject); in Laravel Collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

Sometimes i use things like that in pure php

```
$Subject  = 'this key1, that key2';
$Replaces = ['key1'=>'value1','key2'=>'value2'];
$Return   = str_replace(array_keys($Replaces), array_values($Replaces), $Subject);
// should return 'this value1, that value2
```

In Laravel collection that doesn't work, unless you convert the collection toArray();

so `str_replace($Replaces->keys(), $Replaces->values(), $subject); // doesn't work`

and `str_replace(array_keys($Replaces->toArray(),...); // works`

So, is it possible to achieve that by using collection?

---

I have no reason whatsoever to use collection, i just had that question in mind and thought to look it up, no i'm not stuck here! and i know that it's gonna be slower to use collection than to user pure php, but it's just something to scratch head with!

and thanks!

Comment: Note: the `str_replace()` function call in your code has syntax errors and will not execute.

Comment: meh, ill fix it, i wrote it here as example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is it possible to achieve that by using collection?

Collection alone, no. The closest you'll see to this is the `preg_replace_array()` and `Str::replaceArray()` helpers, but those helpers replaces one key at a time and `Illuminate\Support\Collection` does not call those functions anywhere, neither a `str_replace`.